# Select Minimum value of column A where Column B=1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table  AVERAGE

[image]

I want to

```
select * from table where VhrNum=MIN(VhrNum) and EmptyOrNot=1
```

I've Tried this query but it's not working

```
select * 
from   Average 
where  Itmnum='1' 
   and VhrNum = (
                  select  MIN(VhrNum) 
                  from    (
                             select * 
                             from   Average 
                             where  EmptyOrNot = '1'
                          )
                )
```

In my case it's should select the third row

Comment: please post data as text

Comment: "it's not working" is not a problem description. What is not working? Error? Then what's the error. Unexpected result? Then what's the result?

Comment: Why the third row? `MIN()` returns the minimum value - in your case this is "1" and there is no dataset with `VhrNum = 1` AND `EmptyOrNot = '1'`

Comment: @dns_nx OP is selecting `min` from a subset, namely just those records where EmptyOrNot =  '1', which would give `3`

Comment: What is the datatype of `EmptyOrNot`? It looks like numeric, but you are treating it as a string. Same goes for `Itmnum`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just take the `top 1` row and `order by` by the column?

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM [table]
WHERE EmptyOrNot=1
ORDER BY VhrNum
```

Comment: This is work perfectly for me 
Despite of i didn't ask my question in a good way but you got it  
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Use `TOP 1` with `ORDER BY`

```
select Top 1 * from table where EmptyOrNot=1
Order by VhrNum ASC
```

If you more than one record with min `VhrNum` value and you want all the tie records then use `TOP 1 WITH TIES`

```
select Top 1 With Ties * from table where EmptyOrNot=1
Order by VhrNum ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
 SELECT MIN(VhrNum) FROM table_name where EmptyOrNot=1;
```

Comment: It's work if i just want the VhrNum column value but i need all columns 
And thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions need a `GROUP BY` - or you could `ORDER BY` and select the first.

Aggregate won't let you do a `SELECT *`, which isn't really good practice anyway, and aggregate makes it clearer that you're actually trying to get the `MIN` of this.  `TOP 1/ORDER BY` would let you do a `SELECT *`, but may be less immediately clear that all you're really trying to get is the `MIN(VhrNum)`.

Aggregate:

```
SELECT MIN(VhrNum)
FROM Average
WHERE EmptyOrNot = 1
GROUP BY EmptyOrNot
```

Top:

```
SELECT TOP(1) VhrNum, *
FROM Average
WHERE EmptyOrNot = 1
ORDER BY VhrNum ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select top 1 * from table where VhrNum= (select min(VhrNum) from table);
```

Comment: Better answers along this line have already been given, a `top ` without an `order by` gives non-deterministic results. You're also missing the `emptyOrNot` and `Itmnum` criteria